# memory corruption passing string from c++ dll to mono (C#)

Tags: c#, c++, dll, mono, memory-corruption

I am writing a C# GUI for a C++ application of mine. I retrieve the details of a plugin by enumerating the available DLLs, dynamically loading them one by one, and calling a function called "getdescstring" which returns the plugin description concatenated into a string.

This works flawlessly on Windows. However, when I try to run it on a Linux box (I have tried it on a Linux Mint 64-bit (Mono 3.0.6), and a Xubuntu 32-bit (Mono 2.10.8) virtual machine, g++-4.7 on both) most of the returned strings are corrupted like this:

```
"grown|Barabasi-Albert grown network.|1,000|1.0|1.0|1.0||n|Number of nodes|numeric|k|Degree of neA\0\0…"
```

If I call the function from a standalone C++ test program, it works. No memory leak or corruption with Valgrind. When I try to run the whole program with Mono through Valgrind, it crashes on initialization, so I can't report on that.

So I suspect some memory corruption somewhere between Mono and the DLL, but I cannot identify the location.

**Update:**
My intuition is that calling conventions get mixed up somehow. Since 64-bit programs have unique calling conventions, maybe Mono uses ms_abi, which may conflict with sysv_abi in Unix. However, there are no calling convention flags for these, so even if this it the problem, I cannot fix it. I can set the CC to stdcall in Mono, but g++ ignores any CC attibute on 64-bit CPUs. **No. I tried setting the conventions to stdcall at both ends in a 32-bit virtual machine, but no change**

Here is the code called in the DLL (the function "description" returns a std::vector of strings, but passing a std::vector directly to C# seemed quite nasty)

```
extern "C" const char* getdescstring()
{
vector<vector<string> > descvec=description();
string descstr;
for(unsigned i=0;i<descvec.size();i++)
{
    for(unsigned j=0;j<descvec[i].size();j++)
    {
        descstr+=descvec[i][j];
        descstr+="|";
    }
    descstr+="|";
}
return descstr.c_str();
}
```

And this is the receiving function which transforms the given string back:

```
public static List<List<string>> GetPluginDesc(string plugin)
   {
    List<List<string>> des = new List<List<string>>();
    DllLoadUtils dl;
    if (OS == platform.Windows) dl = new DllLoadUtilsWindows();
    else dl = new DllLoadUtilsLinux();
    IntPtr dllh = dl.LoadLibrary(plugin);
    if (dllh == IntPtr.Zero) return null;
    IntPtr proc = dl.GetProcAddress(dllh, "getdescstring");
    if (proc == IntPtr.Zero) return null;
    dsc descr = (dsc)Marshal.GetDelegateForFunctionPointer(proc, typeof(dsc));
    String descstr =  Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi(descr());
    string[] descelem = descstr.Split('|');
    List<string> ls = new List<string>();
    foreach (string s in descelem)
        {
            //double pipe means EOL
            if (s == "") { des.Add(ls); ls = new List<string>(); } 
            else ls.Add(s);
        }
    if (ls.Count > 0) des.Add(ls);
    dl.FreeLibrary(dllh);
    return des;
}
```

I have also tried this approach (modifying the delegate and the function in the DLL to accept a char* and a length as a parameter), but the results were even worse, no sensible data was transmitted:

```
dsc descr = (dsc)Marshal.GetDelegateForFunctionPointer (proc, typeof(dsc));
IntPtr sf = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(1024);    
descr (sf,1024);
String descstr =  Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi(sf);
Marshal.FreeHGlobal(sf);
```

I would appreciate any help.
Thanks in advance!

I have also copied the DLL loaders and the delegate declaration here, if it can help:

```
interface DllLoadUtils {
            IntPtr LoadLibrary(string fileName);
            void FreeLibrary(IntPtr handle);
            IntPtr GetProcAddress(IntPtr dllHandle, string name);
        }


 public class DllLoadUtilsWindows : DllLoadUtils {
     void DllLoadUtils.FreeLibrary(IntPtr handle) {
         FreeLibrary(handle);
     }

     IntPtr DllLoadUtils.GetProcAddress(IntPtr dllHandle, string name) {
         return GetProcAddress(dllHandle, name);
     }

     IntPtr DllLoadUtils.LoadLibrary(string fileName) {
         return LoadLibrary(fileName);
     }

     [DllImport("kernel32")]
     private static extern IntPtr LoadLibrary(string fileName);

     [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
     private static extern int FreeLibrary(IntPtr handle);

     [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
     private static extern IntPtr GetProcAddress (IntPtr handle, string procedureName);
 }

 internal class DllLoadUtilsLinux : DllLoadUtils {
     public IntPtr LoadLibrary(string fileName) {
         return dlopen(fileName, RTLD_NOW);
     }

     public void FreeLibrary(IntPtr handle) {
         dlclose(handle);
     }

     public IntPtr GetProcAddress(IntPtr dllHandle, string name) {
         // clear previous errors if any
         dlerror();
         var res = dlsym(dllHandle, name);
         var errPtr = dlerror();
         if (errPtr != IntPtr.Zero) {
             MessageBox.Show("dlsym: " + Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi(errPtr));
         }
         return res;
     }

     const int RTLD_NOW = 2;

     [DllImport("libdl.so")]
     private static extern IntPtr dlopen(String fileName, int flags);

     [DllImport("libdl.so")]
     private static extern IntPtr dlsym(IntPtr handle, String symbol);

     [DllImport("libdl.so")]
     private static extern int dlclose(IntPtr handle);

     [DllImport("libdl.so")]
     private static extern IntPtr dlerror();
 }
```

the delegate is simply:

```
public delegate IntPtr dsc();
```

Answer (score 0):

You are returning `descstr.c_str()` which is declared on the stack in your `getdescstring` function.  The memory it refers to is invalid as soon as the function returns.  Try making `descstr.c_str()` so it stays in scope (e.g. as a global variable).

Comment: Thanks for your input.

I have written the following code:


I know it's ugly, just wanted to try it quickly.


    `char desc[2000];
    extern "C" const char* getdescstring()
    {
 vector<vector<string> > descvec=description();
 string descstr;
 for(unsigned i=0;i<descvec.size();i++)
 {
  for(unsigned j=0;j<descvec[i].size();j++)
  {
   descstr+=descvec[i][j];
   descstr+="|";
  }
  descstr+="|";
 }
 strncpy(desc,descstr.c_str(),strlen(descstr.c_str()));
 return desc;
    }`

but it doesn't work, it also trashes the returned string in roughly 50% of the cases.

Sorry for the missing breaks.

Comment: `strncpy` does not null terminate the string.  Try `memset`ting the desc buffer to binary 0 before use or else adding a binary 0 to the end of the copied string.

Comment: If this was the problem I should have seen the string itself completely with a lot of junk at the end, shouldn't I? But they are cut in half if not complete garbage.
I did try it, but the results were the same.